# Spring Security - @Secured works only in mvc Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security + MVC.
The annotation `@Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })` works fine only in the controller layer.
If I try to use it in deeper/other layers, I get no security error.
Or if i am trying to use it on "none mvc mapped" methods, I get no security error.
following my xml's config files:
**web.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j-myapp.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Management/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.affiliates" />

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 

            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        access-denied-page="/Management/auth/denied">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Management/auth/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Management/main/admin"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Management/api/affiliates/**"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/Management/auth/login/"
            authentication-failure-url="/Management/auth/login?error=true"
            login-processing-url="/Management/auth/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/Management/auth/login?error=false" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/Management/auth/login/" logout-url="/Management/auth/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"
        id="passwordEncoder" />
    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.affiliates.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />
</beans>
```

**mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.affiliates.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**applocationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
        as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
        correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.affiliates" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming 
        model. Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Here is how i use it:
the secured method:

```
 @Component
    public  class BrandsApi{
    @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
        public ResultContainer getAll() {
            return brandDao.getAll(getSecurityFilter().getBrandSecurityFilter());
        }
    }
}
```

The caller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/brands")
public class BrandsController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/get")
    public ModelAndView get(){
       BrandsApi brandsApi = new BrandsApi();
       brandsApi.getAll();
}
}
```

**So this is my latest update**:
Hi,
I have a converted my config into javaconfig file that is working fine.
i debug my application in loading time and i see that the parameter is been transfered.
meaning that the brandsApi is initialized
Code:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringJavaConfig { 
    @Bean
    public BrandsApi brandsApi(){
        return new BrandsApi();
    }
}
```

inside BrandsApi I have a method with @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" }) above it

this is how i call the method:
Code:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringJavaConfig.class);
    BrandsApi brandsApi = (BrandsApi)ctx.getBean(BrandsApi.class);
        brandsApi.getAll();
```

but for some reason i can get inside even though I have logged in ROLE_EMPLOYEE
this is my BrandsApi class:
Code:

```
class BrandsApi extends BaseApi{
    @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
    public void getAll() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide any example of "deeper/other layers" with their creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The annotation only has an effect if the instance was created by Spring. You must turn every class, where you want to use this, into a bean and register it in the application context.

Also note that the annotation is ignored if you make internal calls:

```
 Foo foo = context.getBean( "foo", Foo.class );
 foo.foo(); // <-- annotatoon works here
```

but if `foo()` calls `this.foo2()`, there is no check anymore. So any annotations for `foo2()` are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me in which xml do i need to register the bean. and little example will help alot, thanks

Comment: You need to add them to `applocationContext.xml` or you need to add the correct annotaions to the class (since you use `context:component-scan`). In this case, it should be @Component, I think. I suggest to create a small test case to make sure it works as you want.

Comment: I don't have an example; this is from memory :-)

Comment: @Aaron Digulla - I tried that already and it is not working... I edit my post

Comment: You must not call `new`. Use `context.getBean( BrandsApi.class )` instead.

Comment: I get NullPointerException. because the brandsApi is not initialized probabl

Comment: @fatnjazzy Please edit your code to show package names of classes.

Comment: @fatnjazzy: Is `BrandsApi` in the package `com.affiliates`? If not, move it there or modify `context:component-scan` in `applocationContext.xml`

Comment: YEs it is, but I have managed to load the brandApi, I have edit my post again, Thanks for your time

Comment: @fatnjazzy So after adding SpringJavaConfig, the ctx.getBean(..) code is in Controller now?

Comment: Thanks. I have moved to interface and it is working fine. thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Note that you can get the current AppContext easily by implementing `ApplicationContextAware`. Spring will then inject the context in your bean, so you don't need hacks like creating a new `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.